# What are the guarantees of a Hazelcast transaction?

Tags: transactions, atomic, hazelcast, acid

Hazelcast has a notion of transactions, you can put multiple entries to a distributed map in a transactional manner. I'm wondering, which of the ACID properties are guaranteed for a Hazelcast transaction?

In the [documentation](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-dev/manual/html-single/index.html#transactions), it is stated that transactions are isolated with a specific isolation level, and that they are durable as long as you use `TWO_PHASE` transaction type. I assumed that transactions are also atomic, as this is the basic notion of transactions, but we've found recently [some cases where they are not](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/15542). So based on your experience - can I rely on Hazelcast transactions?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit vague and open ended. A use case or a test case that fails and/or does not adhere to documented behavior would be helpful to answer. As far as the Github issue is concerned, I have just updated the ticket and here is the explanation again - in order to cancel a put operation in MapInterceptor, you need to throw an exception, see the Javadoc:
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/map/MapInterceptor.java#L76

For ACID compliancy, Hazelcast supports ONE_PHASE, TWO_PHASE and XA transactions with different isolation levels. XA transactions will help preserving ACID properties across distributed applications.

Comment: Maybe the reproduction code in github issue is not clear enough, but an exception is thrown from the `MapInterceptor.interceptPut()`, by the method `checkState()` ([from guava library](https://guava.dev/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html#checkState-boolean-)). So seems that we do it as stated in Hazelcast documentation. Moreover the same non-atomicity happens when instead of an exception from interceptor, during the operation one node dies.